# Updating an ko.observable doesnt reflect an UI using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am using wizmo grid and binded to an model created as an StockData :

//My view model :

```
function StockData(data)
{
var self=this;
self.Symbol = data.Symbol;
self.LTP=ko.observable(data.LTP);
};
```

//Adding data after an success of an ajax service call

```
    var arr[];
    jsondata=event.data.value;
    $.each(jsonData,function(i)
    {
    vm.WijGridViewModel.Data.push(new StockData({Symbol:jsonData[i].Symbol,LTP:jsonData[i].LTP}));
    });
ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.WijGridViewModel.Data(),function(item)
{
vm.WijGridViewModel.FilteredData.push(item);
});
```

***Updating the data***

**working one below -> but the reason i dont want to use this is as it just replaces the whole old item in observable[] to the new one , whereas i am looking to just update an single field thats LTP. I tried below replacing whole new item to old , and noticed that with an huge data and with real time it gives me an performance issue**

```
var newItem = event.data.value1;
var index = event.data.value2;
vm.WijGridViewModel.FilteredData.replace(
vm.WijGridViewModel.FilteredData()[index],
{Symbol:newItem.Symbol,LTP:newItem .LTP});
```

**so far i tried this ,it updates an observable but doesnt updates an ui :**

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.WijGridViewModel.FilteredData(),function(item)
{
  if(item.Symbol==newItem.Symbol)
{
  item.LTP= newItem.LTP;
}
});
```

//common class for interaction with wijgrid

```
function WijGridViewModel(){
var self=this;
self.data=ko.observableArray();
self.FilteredData=ko.observableArray();
return
{
Data:self.data,
FilteredData:self.FilteredData
}
}
```

using wijgrid

```
<table id="dataGrid" data-bind="wijgrid:{data:WijGridViewModel.FilteredData}">
```

Facing an issue on updating an wijgrid when updateing observable field.
Any help on this is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observable is a function, so to get it's value, you call it:

```
var value = item.LTP();
```

And to set the value, you pass in the new value to the method:

```
item.LTP(newValue);
```

So to update just the LTP, maybe you could try this (it's hard to say exactly without a complete example):

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.WijGridViewModel.FilteredData(),function(item)
{
  if(item.Symbol==newItem.Symbol)
  {
    item.LTP(newItem.LTP());
  }
});
```